# Having problems enabling new modules on local Drupal 7 site

Tags: drupal

I have created a local version of my Drupal website to do dev work on. But when I add new modules to the local version they do install but they do not enable correctly. For example I added the legal module, enabled it, but when I go to site configuration to edit it, the legal section does not appear. Any help please?

Comment: how did you enable the module? have you manually tried running cron and/or clearing the cache?

Comment: I enabled the module by clicking on the checkbox on the modules tab and I have tried both running cron and clearing the cache but still no joy... any other ideas?

Comment: I just installed and enabled the legal module on a fresh D7 install and it was listed on the admin configuration page under people, and navigating to the path 'admin/config/people/legal' worked as well. you said you have installed multiple new modules. you may have to go through and deactivate the modules one by one to see if any of them are preventing the legal module from being added to the menu paths.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that not enough memory will be allocated to the service to allow for new modules which require more memory to be ran, try putting

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

in the `sites/default/settings.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old thread but thought it was worth adding the following.

I had this problem recently on a local dev install (using Acquia Dev Desktop, by the way). Turning off the Memcache module resolved my issue.